# Delay channel read in Netty 4

Tags: java, netty

Is there a way to tell **netty 4** to stop reading from a channel until it's reenabled?

I want clients to send me their credentials followed by some data. For the ease of this protocol I don't want to have the clients to wait for an OK or ERROR until they can send their data. Maybe there is a DelayHandler or something like that'll just put all received buffers into a queue but I could not find something like that.

Since the verification is not done instantaneously I would have to block the network thread, which - of course - is a bad idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the AUTO_READ ChannelOption, which allows you to control when you read data.

E.g. https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/proxy/HexDumpProxy.java

Answer (score 0):

One way that may suit your purpose is to use a `ReplayingDecoder`: each time a chunk of input comes in, you will be presented with it, and each time you'll have the option to say "no, that's not enough input; when more input comes in, ask me again." The whole input will accumulate and will be *replayed* to you for maximum convenience.

Comment: Its not that I would really need more data. It's just that I can't handle the incoming data until I have authenticated the client. Sure, a ReplayDecoder could do this but that's not what it is intended for and I might not even receive any data after the authentication check.